# JS/jquery - add textbox on doubleclick and update table field(s)

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello dear programmers,

i'm trying to update table fields with ajax.

doubleclick on a table cell, the cell content will be replaced with a textbox and after changing the text, it updates the cell value with the textbox value.

my problem is, the first change works fine, but after the second change, all table cells changed before are updated with the new value and not only the one clicked.

would be great if someone can help me out and point me to right direction.

you can find the whole thing to test on http://jsfiddle.net/bDxDX/3/

```
$(function () {
    $(".doodleEdit").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(this);
        var value = $(this).html();
        updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {

    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');

    var mode = $(currentEle).attr('class').split(' ')[1];

    if (mode == 'editDescr') {
        alert("editDescr");
    } else if (mode == 'addDate') {
        alert("addDate");
    } else if (mode == 'addVote') {
        alert("addVote");
    }

    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
        }
    });

    $(document).click(function () {
            $(currentEle).html($(".thVal").val().trim());
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bDxDX/3/

many thanks and best regards
costal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your case ? Please check this jsfiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/hellomaya/bDxDX/5/

```
$(function () {
    $(".doodleEdit").dblclick(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var currentEle = $(e.target);
        var value = $(e.target).html();

        console.log($(e.target));

        if ($.trim(value) === "") {
            $(currentEle).data('mode', 'add');
        } else {
            $(currentEle).data('mode', 'edit');
        }
        updateVal(currentEle, value);
    });
});

function updateVal(currentEle, value) {

    $(currentEle).html('<input class="thVal" type="text" value="' + value + '" />');

    var mode = $(currentEle).data('mode');
    alert(mode);

    $(".thVal").focus();
    $(".thVal").keyup(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            $(this).parent().html($(this).val().trim());
            $(".thVal").remove();
        }
    });
}

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(".thVal") !== undefined) {
        if ($(".thVal").val() !== undefined) {
            $(".thVal").parent().html($(".thVal").val().trim());
            $(".thVal").remove();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did something very similar and thought this was a pretty concise way to do it.  It assumes you want use the Enter key (key code 13) to write the input data back to the table cell, and Escape (code 27) to close the input without writing to the cell.

```
$("#table").on('dblclick', 'td', function() {
    var cell_data = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith('<td><input id="temp_enter"></input></td>');

    $("#temp_enter").keyup( function(event) {
        if (event.which == 13) {
            $(this).parent().replaceWith('<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>');
        } else if (event.which == 27) {
            $(this).parent().replaceWith('<td>' + cell_data + '</td>');
        }
    });
});
```